# GLSL interactive lighting

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, light, shaders

Often when I'm doing something in the GLSL shading mode I always need that extra interactivity for viewing what's going on with my scene. With all the materials assigned and lamps in place, from time to time I want to be able to change the lighting as if I'm using a MatCap as its influence. However, this is not quite good because the material properties will be lost, mostly specular effects because for the MatCap to take effect you're required to set the materials to "Shadeless". Are there any workarounds around this?